# use search-forward to determine bound of another search-forward

Tags: error-handling, forward-search

I'm trying to use lisp to search for a pattern bounded by another one across a BiBTeX file.

Let's say the following is the file I want to search in

```
% Created using Papers on Wed, 07 Apr 2021.
%% http://papersapp.com/papers/

@article{Liquet:2012bb,
author = {Liquet, Benoit and Timsit, Jean-Fran{\c c}ois and Rondeau, Virginie},
title = {{Investigating hospital heterogeneity with a multi-state frailty model: application to nosocomial pneumonia disease in intensive care units.}},
journal = {BMC Medical Research Methodology},
year = {2012},
volume = {12},
number = {1},
pages = {79},
month = jun
}

@article{Sayre:2010ip,
author = {Sayre, Michael R and O'Connor, Robert E and Atkins, Dianne L and Billi, John E and Callaway, Clifton W and Shuster, Michael and Eigel, Brian and Montgomery, William H and Hickey, Robert W and Jacobs, Ian and Nadkarni, Vinay M and Morley, Peter T and Semenko, Tanya I and Hazinski, Mary Fran},
title = {{Part 2: evidence evaluation and management of potential or perceived conflicts of interest: 2010 American Heart Association Guidelines for Cardiopulmonary Resuscitation and Emergency Cardiovascular Care.}},
journal = {Circulation},
year = {2010},
volume = {122},
number = {18 Suppl 3},
pages = {S657--64},
month = nov
}

@article{Indrambarya:2009gd,
author = {Indrambarya, Toonchai and Boyd, John H and Wang, Yingjin and McConechy, Melissa and Walley, Keith R},
title = {{Low-dose vasopressin infusion results in increased mortality and cardiac dysfunction following ischemia-reperfusion injury in mice.}},
journal = {Critical care (London, England)},
year = {2009},
volume = {13},
number = {3},
pages = {R98},
file = {~/Dropbox/geri-biblio_BibTeX/full/vasopressine/sepsis/Indrambarya:2009gd.pdf}
}

@article{Adrogue:1981ts,
author = {Adrogu{\'e}, H J and Madias, N E},
title = {{Changes in plasma potassium concentration during acute acid-base disturbances.}},
journal = {The American journal of medicine},
year = {1981},
volume = {71},
number = {3},
pages = {456--467},
month = sep
}
```

The idea is to match the STRING into a "file = {STRING}" strictly into the same BiBTeX entry. Otherwise, I want to get an error message.
For instance for the first entry, I should get an error message. In the third one, the cursor should find the STRING.

I've written the following

```
(if
      (search-forward "file = {" (match-beginning (search-forward "@")) t 1)
      (match-string-no-properties 0)
    ;;; il faut aussi voir le problème de la dernière citation (donc pas d'autre @ derrière)
    (error "Pas de fichier PDF associé"))
  (progn
    (setq pfile (point))
    (mark-inside-delimiters)
    (kill-ring-save pfile p_end)))
```

using the `(mark-inside-delimiters)` function from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3919432/is-there-a-way-to-copy-an-entire-line-until-a-stop-character-in-emacs

I do not understand why this does not work.
When I'm in the third entry, the bound is point 1591. And the following       `(search-forward "file = {" 1591 t 1)` works...

Comment: For starters you're passing `(search-forward "@")` as the SUBEXP argument to `match-beginning`.  SUBEXP is an optional integer argument indicating which subexpression (regexp group) of the matched text you're referring to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When searching, Emacs starts from the current point. Also, when it searches, it moves the point forward until it finds a match (or reaches the end of the buffer).

After your first search, the point is located already after the entry you would like to search in.

To start the second search from the same place as from where you started the first search, you could wrap that first search in a `save-excursion`:

```lisp
(let ((limit (save-excursion
               (search-forward-regexp "^@"))))
  (search-forward-regexp "^[[:space:]]*file.*{\\(.*\\)}$")
  (match-string 1))
```

Alternatively, you could use `(thing-at-point 'defun)`, to extract the current entry as a string (which I found by some 'educated guess', that it does correctly). Then you can search within that string in some temporary buffer, for example:

```lisp
(let ((s (thing-at-point 'defun)))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (insert s)
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (search-forward-regexp "^[[:space:]]*file.*{\\(.*\\)}$")
    (match-string 1)))
```